# Is it possible to embed an image in Keynote with just the URL, so it loads every time?

Tags: graphics, keynote

I would like to have a way of making Keynote load a new version of an image dynamically the way a web page would, getting the latest version every time the Keynote deck is used, rather than copying and pasting the image itself into the Keynote slide deck.

Is there any way to do this?

Searching turned up [nothing useful for Keynote](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250263105), although [it does appear to be possible with PowerPoint](https://www.presentationpoint.com/link-internet-image-powerpoint/).

Oddly, it's easy to point to a YouTube video with a URL, and I presume that the video is loaded fresh every time rather than downloaded and embedded in the Keynote file.  So they obviously recognized this need, but if they offer this ability with static images, they have hidden it very well.

(The goal, since I know someone will want to know, is that charts and graphs generated in an outside app can be made a part of the slide deck without any need to update it.)

Comment: The reason YT videos get linked is most likely disk space related. Having dynamic loading for images would for sure be useful though.

Comment: Also, a similar question has come up before -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191812/how-can-i-create-a-live-updating-slideshow

Comment: The closest way using Keynote would be to add a link to a Web page an object and click on it between two slides

Comment: It may be slightly similar, but the other question is basically asking for MS OLE on macOS, while I am merely looking for a basic `img` tag like every browser has.